# Use of Sensitivity and Specificity

Tags: regression

How to check the accuracy of a regression model? Do we really need to check Sensitivity and Specificity to find the accuracy of the model? Or it is only used for classification problems and logistic regression?

Answer (score 0):

Sensitivity and Specificity are both used for classification problems.

If you want to compare accuracy of a linear regression model you can compare the **Adjusted R-squared** values of models or their **Root Mean Squared Error**. You can find the RMSE by using the `predict` function on a testing set, having already built your model on your training set. If you don't know what I am talking about then you should read [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/05/improve-model-performance-cross-validation-in-python-r/).

Remember that you are only comparing the adjusted R-squared value against a similar model. You cannot compare completely different models to objectively conclude one is better than another.